# Send data from native to flutter

Tags: flutter

Im extending the native implementation of `FirebaseMessagingService` to wait for push notifications in native `android`.

I need to start my flutter app when the user clicks the push notification, so.. How can I send data to my flutter app?

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but is there a reason why you wouldn't just use the [Firebase Messaging plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_messaging)?

Comment: @rmtmckenzie yes, Im using Parse Server, and the implementation/data is a quite different https://parseplatform.org/

Comment: Ah fair enough, probably worth mentioning that in the question. But couldn't you still do a check for if you're on android, and if so activate and use the firebase messaging plugin there, and wrap the plugin with a bit of dart logic to massage the data back into the Parse format... I may be missing something here but if the push notification is being sent by Parse through firebase, while it's going through firebase it would still theoretically have to adhere to the firebase data format wouldn't it?

Comment: Its a good question,because sometimes we want customization in the notification

Answer (score 1):

**In Flutter**

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ScreenPage(),
    );
  }
}
class ScreenPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScreenPageState createState() => _ScreenPageState();
}

class _ScreenPageState extends State<ScreenPage> {
  
  static const platform = const MethodChannel("myChannel");

  @override
  void initState() {
    platform.setMethodCallHandler(nativeMethodCallHandler);
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<dynamic> nativeMethodCallHandler(MethodCall methodCall) async {
    print('Native call!');
    switch (methodCall.method) {
      case "methodNameItz" :
        return "This data from flutter.....";
        break;
      default:
        return "Nothing";
        break;
    }
  }



  
  
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    //return ();
  }
 
}
```

**In Java**

```java
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
//import io.flutter.view.FlutterNativeView;


public class MyJavaFile extends FlutterActivity {

    Button clickMeButton;
    MethodChannel channel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        channel = new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), "myChannel");

        setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);
        clickMeButton = findViewById(R.id.clickMeButton);
        
        clickMeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            
                channel.invokeMethod("methodNameItz", null, new MethodChannel.Result() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Object o) {
                        Log.d("Results", o.toString());
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void error(String s, String s1, Object o) {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void notImplemented() {
                    }

                });

            }
        });



    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still basically look at the [firebase messaging example](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/ios/Classes/FirebaseMessagingPlugin.m#L119-L125) (or [the same for android](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebasemessaging/FirebaseMessagingPlugin.java#L77))

1. Create a [Platform Channel](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) in your `AppDelegate` (or `MainActivity` on android) and the register for the same channel on the dart/flutter side (maybe `main.dart` and register a method like `onPushClicked`)
2. Listen for your parse messages in your native code
3. Send them to your dart code using the platform channel (as seen in the above linked example) `channel.invokeMethod('onPushClicked', myMessageArguments)`

Comment: What about when the app is closed? I need to pass data to the app

Comment: Your question was regarding "start my flutter app when the user clicks the push notification" -- so when the user clicks on the push notification, your app is in the foreground. Getting dart code run and interact with plugins in the background is a whole other can of worms. see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21925 and follow https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24278 and the best manual right now https://medium.com/flutter-io/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124 - ie. wait a few weeks until the medium post gets updated *hopefully*

Answer (score 0):

**flutter**

```
Map<String,dynamic> data = <String,dynamic>{};
final res = await methodChannel.invokeMethod('getDistance');
  data = Map<String,dynamic>.from(res);
   final dis = data['distance'] as String;
   final tim = data['time'] as String;
```

**ios native**

```
 switch call.method {

    case "getDistance":
    let data = 
     ["distance":routeFormattedDistance,"time":routeFormattedTravelTime]
     result(data)
    default :
     result("")
}
```