# Flutter EventChannel Confusion

Tags: java, android, flutter, listener

I am having a hard time connecting the dots on how to setup my EventChannel natively in Java and looking for some help.

I am using MethodChannel to have flutter call directly into Native android code.  A couple of the methods of the MethodChannel will setup Listeners in my Java classes (data from bluetooth devices) and I would like to send the data back to the flutter/dart code over an EventChannel.   The event will be initiated from the java/android side and sent into the dart/flutter side.  I am not connecting the dots on how to "push" the event over to flutter.

This is what I have done but it doesn't seem right.  How can I get my bluetooth event (deviceEvent method) to pass it's data to the EventChannel?

Any help is much appreciated.

**Class Declaration - Extended FlutterActivity**

```
public class MyCustomClass extends FlutterActivity implements FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler,  DeviceServiceListener {
```

**Overrode OnCreate:**

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    BinaryMessenger binaryMessenger =getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger();
    getContext().startActivity(
            FlutterActivity.createDefaultIntent(getApplicationContext())
    );

    eventChannel = new EventChannel(binaryMessenger, STREAM);
    streamHandler = new EventChannel.StreamHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onListen(Object arguments, EventChannel.EventSink events) {
            events.success(arguments);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel(Object arguments) {
            Log.e("platform_channel", "arguments: " + arguments.toString());

        }
    };
    eventChannel.setStreamHandler(streamHandler);
}
```

**Device Event (data from bluetooth) - defined in the interface of DeviceServiceListener**

```
 @Override
    public void deviceEvent(ListenerMessage message) {

        //I am not sure how to get my bluetooth data event into my flutter EventChannel

    }
```

Comment: Related: [Send data from native to flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55107498/295004)

Comment: Thank you but I don't think that example is using the EventChannel.  That example appears to be using a methodChannel to send data back.  I guess I could do that but given that this is event driven (e.g. when the BT device sends data) I was hoping to use the EventChannel to send data.  

Maybe I am not understanding how the EventChannel is intended to work?

Comment: Ah didn't see the distinction. When in doubt, check an existing implementation: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/sensors